# Protected areas vs. using private areas in base classes

Tags: c#, c++, .net

I heard that it is not good to use protected members, because it breaks the encapsulation of base class. I need to know what are the advantages of using protected members over private members or vice-verse in base classes. Can anyone help?

Comment: Most uses of protected inheritance I've seen have been pointless; they could just as well have been private, but the class designer apparently didn't have a clear specification in mind, so made them protected "just in case".

Comment: `"just in case"` or `"i see i will need it sometime"` are amongst the most cumbersome design decisions. Either you need it, or you don't. No exceptions...

Comment: @MareInfinitus: Not in the real world, where going back and making it protected has cost attached to it. If you're writing a class with extensibility/reusability in mind, then protected makes sense in anticipation of future requiremnts.

Comment: @JonEgerton: The software that I'm developing is mostly used in the real world. If you have a good design, it is obviours which parts to make private and which to make protected. And of course, the public parts are very clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no clear advantage of using protected members over using private members. It is conceptually different in any way.

private: You can only use your member inside the class

protected: Member can be used inside the class and inside it's subclasses, but not from outside

public: Member can be called and seen anywhere inside and outside the class

This means: Choose your concept based on what you want to express! If you have to override members, make them protected.

What is definitly not recommend is to make members protected for the "just in case" situation. If you want to express that there is a hook which can be overriden, then and only then, make them protected. This has to be expressed in your code elsewhere, e.g. where the overriden member is used.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you have a function in a base class that should not be used from outside the class, but it might have to be overridden by a sub-class. Then you can make it protected.

Answer (score 1):

Actually we cannot talk about advantage or disadvantages between private and protected. What ever you do inheritance will always break encapsulation in some way. You must set access modifiers according to requirements. If derived classes want (or need) to use or override a method from base class, you can make it protected otherwise it should be private.